# WPF CommandParameter GridViewColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, xaml, commandparameter

my question is: Is it possible to use a GridViewColumnHeader as a CommandParameter? I have the following code and I want to use the clicked ColumnHeader as the CommandParameter:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Vorname}">
      <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Vorname" Command="{Binding Path=ColumnHeaderClickCommand}"/>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: You want to use the control itself or the contents of the header as a parameter?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot! I only need the clicked ColumnHeader as a parameter. I have access to the list itself in my Viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ColumnHeaderClickCommand` is an `ICommand`:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Vorname}">
     <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Vorname" Command="{Binding Path=ColumnHeaderClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: may be helpfull: ((Binding)((GridViewColumnHeader)parameter).Column.DisplayMemberBinding).Path.Path;